# Jelly bean notification issue

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a progress bar displayed at the status bar, when the status bar is expanded the progressbar flickers. Till Ics the same code was working fine. Now in Jelly bean I see this issue. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions on the solution?

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to set some flags like

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
pb.setCancelable(false);
```

only when you click on that expandable pb than cancel it

Comment: `ProgressBar` has no method called `setCancelable` if you meant `ProgressDialog` this answer is not good since `ProgressDialog` has nothing to do with Status/Notification